# Note taking app with a hand guard/hand recognition feature?

Tags: notes, stylus

I have an Asus Transformer Eee Pad. I recently purchased a stylus that allows for pen-precise writing and wanted to utilize my tablet as a note taking device.

I have found several apps for this purpose, but none of them allow for recognition of my hand, which confuses the screen. If I rest my hand on the edges of the tablet I am fine, but that only works if I am writing on the outer edges of the "sheet", and I would ideally like to utilize the whole page for notes.

**Does anyone know if there is an app for Android tablets out there that is capable of this functionality?**

My friend's iPad had an app that allowed him to designate a "dead" area of his screen so he could rest his hand on it and the iPad ignored input from that area, allowing him to take notes with ease and I admit I was pretty jealous. I'm hoping there is some similar app out there for Android. Thank you in advance for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Side note: what stylus have you bought that allows for pen-precise writing? I'm trying to find one for months... @chris

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini though it's been a year since you left your comment, I just got an adonit jot pro that works very well: http://adonit.net

Answer (score 2):

The general rule is to make sure you touch your device with your stylus first then rest your palm, it helps big time. Unfortunately, I have not seen an app with a dead area, but that means its not the "whole page".

Samsung are the leaders for true stylus technology on android with their new [Galaxy Note phone/tablet](http://www.samsung.com/global/microsite/galaxynote/note/benefit.html?type=find) which may be the best choice for this kind of thing.

May I ask what stylus you purchased? I have not seen any with pen-precise writing, it does not seem possible with the capacitive touch screen when you compare it to Samsung's stylus tech with pressure sensitivity and separate Wacom sensor.

Comment: At the moment (2019) there are still a couple of Android brands including a Touch Screen Digitizer on their phone. As far as I know just Samsung Notes and LG Stylus. Without a Digitizer handwriting has not quality and text recognition became to complicated